# PySimpleGUI with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pysimplegui

I've made a PySimpleGUI app with Selenium, it takes CSV values and puts them into a form and submits it, now however we need to send an input to the form.

So I added this:

```
 [sg.Multiline(size=(30, 5), key='deposit')],
```

But how do I reference it in the send_keys function that I'm using currently:

```
...
            mail_field.send_keys(line[13])
            phone_field.send_keys(line[16])
            deposit_field.send_keys('deposit') ?
            submit.click()
```

Thought I'd try values['deposit'] but that doesnt work either
Entire code

```
import csv
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):

    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


def make_window(theme):

    sg.theme('LightGrey')
    menu_def = [['&Application', ['E&xit']],
                ['&Help', ['&About']]]
    right_click_menu_def = [[], ['Exit']]

    # Table Data

    input_layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-')],


                    [sg.Button("Open File", button_color=(
                        'white', 'dodgerblue'))],

                    [sg.Text('Chrome Version')],

                    [sg.OptionMenu(values=(
                        '96', '97', '98'),  k='-OPTION MENU-', background_color='dodgerblue'), ],
                    
                     [sg.Multiline(size=(30, 5), key='deposit')],

                    [sg.Button('Submit', button_color=('white', '#Ed1941'))]]

    layout = [[sg.Text('Name', size=(35, 1), justification='center', font=(
        "Helvetica", 16), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE, k='-TEXT HEADING-', enable_events=True)]]
    layout += [[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Setup CSV and Chrome Version', input_layout),

                              ]], key='-TAB GROUP-', size=(400, 120))]]

    return sg.Window('Name', layout, icon='icon.ico', right_click_menu=right_click_menu_def)


def main():
    window = make_window(sg.theme('LightGrey'))

    # This is an Event Loop
    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening

        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
                print(key, ' = ', values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
            print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     '')
        elif event == 'Popup':
            print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
            print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")

        elif event == "Open File":
            print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            csv_file_selected = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            # sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            # print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))


def run_selenium(window, file, driver):

    with open(file, 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Web Automation
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver)
    driver.get('')

    fname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FIRSTNAME"]')
    lname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LASTNAME"]')
    phone_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PHONE"]')
    mail_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="EMAIL"]')
    deposit_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DEPOSIT"]')
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="sib-form"]/div[8]/div/button')

    with open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        next(csv_reader)
        for line in csv_reader:

            time.sleep(3.0)

            fname_field.send_keys(line[10])
            lname_field.send_keys(line[11])
            mail_field.send_keys(line[13])
            phone_field.send_keys(line[16])
            deposit_field.send_keys(text) //Here
            submit.click()

    # Not to update GUI in thread, but generate an event which will be processed in event loop.
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)


def main():
    # My GUI
    window = make_window(sg.theme())
    folder_or_file = None
    
    cd97 = resource_path('./chromedriver97.exe')
    cd98 = resource_path('./chromedriver98.exe')
    # Using your path for all the drivers of all versions
    paths = {
        '97': cd97,
        '98': cd98,
    }

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening

        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            # print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            # print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
                print(key, ' = ', values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     '')
        elif event == 'Popup':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
           # print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")
        elif event == "Open File":
            #print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            folder_or_file = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            # sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            #print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))
        elif event == 'Submit':
            version = values['-OPTION MENU-']
            if folder_or_file is None or version not in paths:
              #  print("No CSV file selected or wrong Chrome version selected")
                continue
            # Using thread to avoid long time job will block and cause GUI no response
            threading.Thread(target=run_selenium, args=(
                window, folder_or_file, paths[version])).start()
            # Disable Submit button to prevent submit again when threading
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=True)
          #  print('[LOG] Run Selenium ...')
        elif event == 'Done':
            # Enable Submit button when thread done
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=False)
           # print('[LOG] End Selenium')

    window.close()


main()
```

Comment: In you event loop, `event, values = window.read(); if event == 'Send': text = values['deposit']; send_keys(text)` where there's a button with `key='Send'` in your layout to send text.

Comment: I've added the entire code, where about would those changes come ? Thanks alot for replying

Comment: Pass argument with text, `elif event == 'Submit': text=values['deposit'];...;threading.Thread(target=run_selenium, args=(window, folder_or_file, paths[version], text)).start();...` and one more arguemnt `text` in `def run_selenium(window, file, driver, text):`. Two functions with same name `main`, first one will be overwrite.

Comment: Hey there so its adding that amount in the form thanks so much! However now after it finishes the last entry it goes into an endless loop where it keeps adding that number and trying to submit , is there somewhere else to change the code ?

Comment: Maybe you need to check the code block in `with open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:` where it send once for each line in csv file. Try to find the answer by yourself by adding some print to confirm where it loop.

Comment: Weird, its working without the addition of the new code as it should. Thought maybe the field was adding that count but it just runs endlessly filling in the deposit part with the number

Comment: Ok, that's all I can help !

Comment: Thanks alot Jason much appreciated

Comment: Dont you wanna post the answer part so I mark it as the correct one?

Comment: It is most important that your issue can be solved, not want to spend time to gather all the information.

Answer (score 0):

`elif event == 'Submit': text=values['deposit'];...;threading.Thread(target=run_selenium, args=(window, folder_or_file, paths[version], text)).start();... and one more arguemnt text in def run_selenium(window, file, driver, text):`

Answer by: Jason Yang. https://stackoverflow.com/users/11936135/jason-yang